# How to perform the integration of a root of a non polynomial?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate a function that envolves a root of a non polynomial, to be more specific, this is the function:

$$
x(u) = \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{\left( 1+ \frac{(c-1)M}{2-3Mu}\right) \left(2Mu^{3}-u^{2} + \frac{1}{D^{2}} \right)}} \,\, ,
$$

where $c,M, D$ are all real parameters. If I didn't had the first term inside the root I would know to to integrate, but with this term all gets more difficult, so I don't have any insight about how to perform this integral analytically, I'm avoiding numerical methods. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even with $c=1$, the result is not pleasant ! Very little hope, I am afraid.

Comment: When $c = 1$, it's possible to express the term inside the root as a polynomial, and this integral can be evaluated by means of ellipitic integrals. But, with that functions, i don't know.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I am afraid that numerical methods will be difficult to avoid.